# It looks like my account just got wiped

Tags: support, meta

This probably isn't the right spot to post this, but I just wanted to ask - I just went onto the meta for the first time, and it looks like my account got wiped - the records of questions etc. and badges disappeared, while the rep didn't. Is this just because the meta is officially another SE - if so why did the rep stay? - or is something wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not the first person to be confused by this.  Your account on meta is separate; in addition to separating your posts and comments between meta and main, it can earn different badges than you have on main.  A meta account is automatically created for you the first time you visit meta.  If you go to your user profile, you'll see links from main to meta and meta to main next to the "network profile" link.

There is no meta-specific reputation.  However, I'm guessing, rep-based things like privileges are too "baked in" to sidestep.  Since we need a reputation number, we might as well use the one from main.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, so-called reputation points ("rep") carry over to Meta but history, badges, and other things don't. I assume the reason is that rep isn't earned separately on Meta so it may as well carry over from Main. As to *why* rep isn't earned separately on Meta, I'm guessing it's because people vote on Meta depending on whether they agree with the post, and one shouldn't gain or lose rep on that basis.

Comment: If that's the reason rep isn't accumulated separately on meta, it's interesting then that meta.stackoverflow.com does have its own reputation count.

Comment: Ohh... and apparently it doesn't do that anymore. But where did my Meta SO posts go??

Comment: @Daniel, a while back, they split Meta SO into Meta SO (for questions specific to SO) and [meta.se] (for questions not specific to SO), and divvied up the questions as well as they could.